# Show list of users with comparison two references in Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase I have the "users" where I save all users' information.

Now I want to show someone I like in the "Favor".

This is "Favors"

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9olWt.png]

In "Favor", only my ID and people ID I added to the favor list

And this is "users":

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKqrz.png]

In "users", I have all users' information inside people's ID

And this is my code to show all users

```
database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        users.clear();
        for(DataSnapshot snapshot1: snapshot.getChildren()){
            User user= snapshot1.getValue(User.class);

            if(!user.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && hasChat != null)
                users.add(user);

        }
        binding.recyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter();
        usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

And this code i'm trying to show favor list, but it's show blank:

```
 database.getReference().child("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                users.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot1.getValue(User.class);

                    if (!user.getUid().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()) && user.getUid().equals(database.getReference().child("Favors").getKey()))
                        users.add(user);

                }
                binding.recyclerView.hideShimmerAdapter();
                usersAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Or where are you stuck in extending it?

Comment: I have problem with extending it. Now I want to show a new list of "users" whose id matches the id in "favor"

Comment: The use-case is clear, but I'm not sure where you stuck in implementing it.  Did you try anything for that already? Was there an error mesage?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: Sorry about late, I trying equal two keys but it's not working